# Disable all cookies in lightbox?

Tags: javascript, cookies, session-cookies, lightbox2

within my webpage I use lightbox2 for some functions. Now I found this script seems to set some cookies - which is a mess according to new EU privacy regulations.

So my question: how can I disable the usage of cookies for Lightbox completely?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, lightbox does not create cookies.